# The relationship between simultaneous equations model and seemingly unrelated regression model?

Tags: statistics, systems-of-equations, regression, regression-analysis

recently I try to solve a equations-system. So after read few pieces of paper, I want to use SUR model. Based on what I read, those paper notes that usually equations-system has two method to be solved, say SUR (seemingly unrelated regression) and SEM (simultaneous equations model). And they are two things, people could talk and use them completely separately.

However, today I also read other pieces of paper, those paper confuses me because SEM (simultaneous equations model) and SUR model they look like a one thing? at least they look like doing one thing? Because english is not my first language, and I cannot read very fast, that's why I read many things, I still cannot figure out their differences. so put my confusion here.

Just want to know whether a system could be usually solved by either SEM or SUR. When I discuss SUR or SEM, am I also necessary to mention another one? Furthermore, what reationship between them?

I know so many questions, so couples words are also welcome!

Thank you in advanced.